# Setting expiry for a cookie

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I'm trying to create a cookie when an event is fired on an element. 
So when the element is clicked, this code runs    `let date = new Date();
                                                   date.setTime(date.getTime() + 86400000);
                                                   let exp = "expires= " + date.UTCString();
                                                   let path = "path+/";
                                                   document.cookie = "my=gees;"
                                                   document.cookie = exp;
                                                   document.cookie = path;`

But when I click on the ad, the cookie is created alright but it doesn't delete after the time is up.
Please help.
And also, i had to split the cookie and expiry and path because for some weird reason, adding the semi-colon to the string omits the rest of the string so for instance when i type`let cookie = "my=gees" + exp + path`

the browser saves only up to the first semicolon so i get just`"my=gees"`

Answer (score 0):

To set and delete a cookie after some time use below mention syntax

```
document.cookie = "my=gees; expires=Fri, 1 May 2020 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
```

Comment: adding the semi colon omits the rest of the cookie. So in this case, only `"my=gees"` will be saved.

Comment: semicolen inside a string wont do this you should try this code it will run

Comment: i just did and same results. I thought it was just Chrome but same thing on Internet Explorer.  it saves only `"my=gees"` and ignores the rest of the string